# Send Shell Script in HTML

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to send shell script using the code below. I have fieldsets and input fields within.

For example, I would like to run something like `shell.sh folderPath eightbits lr`

How do I make something like that work when I click the submit button?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <form action="">
        <label for="folderPath">Folder Path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="folderPath" name="folderPath">
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="khz">
            <p>Please Choose Bits: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="eightbits" name="group1"> 8 bits <br>
          <input type="radio" value="sixteenbits" name="group1"> 16 bits <br>
        </fieldset>
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="audio-type">
            <p>Please Choose Type: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="ch12" name="group2"> CH12 <br>
          <input type="radio" value="lr" name="group2"> LR <br>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you want to run it? CLient or browser?

Comment: @JohannesH. Browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['folderPath']) && !empty($_GET['folderPath']) && isset($_GET['group1']) && isset($_GET['group2'])) {
        $run = shell_exec("shell.sh $_GET['folderPath'] $_GET['group1'] $_GET['group2']");
        var_dump($run);
    }
?>
```

Note you should also add some function to verify the `folderPath`.

This will do the same:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['folderPath']) && !empty($_GET['folderPath']) && isset($_GET['group1']) && isset($_GET['group2'])) {

        echo $_GET['folderPath'];
        echo "<br />\n";

        $folderPath = $_GET['folderPath'];
        $group1 = $_GET['group1'];
        $group2 = $_GET['group2'];

        echo $folderPath;
        echo "<br />\n";

        $run = shell_exec("shell.sh $folderPath $group1 $group2");
        var_dump($run);
    }
?>
```

Full sample:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-links">
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <form action="">
        <label for="folderPath">Folder Path:</label>
        <input type="text" id="folderPath" name="folderPath">
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="khz">
            <p>Please Choose Bits: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="eightbits" name="group1"> 8 bits <br>
          <input type="radio" value="sixteenbits" name="group1"> 16 bits <br>
        </fieldset>
    <br></br>
        <fieldset id="audio-type">
            <p>Please Choose Type: </p>
          <input type="radio" value="ch12" name="group2"> CH12 <br>
          <input type="radio" value="lr" name="group2"> LR <br>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

<?php
    if (isset($_GET['folderPath']) && !empty($_GET['folderPath']) && isset($_GET['group1']) && isset($_GET['group2'])) {
        $run = shell_exec("shell.sh $_GET['folderPath'] $_GET['group1'] $_GET['group2']");
        var_dump($run);
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Save this file as: testpage.php

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But how do I separate each fieldset? And I am getting only on value from each values in a fieldset.

Comment: What you mean by: separate each fieldset? If you enter: **123** in folderPath + select **8 bits** and **LR** then this code will run shell script: `shell.sh 123 eightbits lr` thats what you want?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So how do i implement this code? within ```<form action="">``` I would include this PHP file?

Comment: Depends on: Do you want to show the output to user? Add this code on TOP of your HTML code. And rename this file to **.php** instead of **.html** - When you rename it to .php you can add this code anywhere within your HTML code.

Comment: I would like to show the shell output (or progress) to the user.

Comment: This code will not show progress while happening but it will show final output when shell.sh is completed. If you want to show a Progress Bar then you need JavaScript

Comment: So instead of doing it in PHP, I should execute it in Javascript?

Comment: @YuriBurkov you will need PHP to run shell.sh from server side. And JavaScript can control 1 other php script to get status. It also depends on what your shell.sh do. Javascript is not a must.. you can do it without JavaScript but its easy to make it look beautiful with JS.